# Xpath tokenize function inside contains function

Tags: c#, xpath, substring

I would like to know how to use nested string functions in a XPath query. For instance my XML is like below.

```
<Invoice> <cbc:Note>Fatura Tipi:MM Alınan Mlz.İade</cbc:Note> </Invoice>
```

And my C# code is like shown below.

```
cbc:Note[contains(text(), 'Fatura Tipi:')]
```

when I run this code it returns **"Fatura Tipi:MM Alınan Mlz.İade"**  and part is ok.
After that  I want to get second part of string after : delimiter. Meaning I would like to get "**MM Alınan Mlz.İade**" as result.    So I think I need to use nested functions something like below.

```
cbc:Note[ substring-after(contains(text(), 'Fatura Tipi:'),':')]
```

Comment: Could you please show you code?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
substring-after(cbc:Note[contains(., 'Fatura Tipi:')], ':')
```

(Note, `contains(., ...)` is generally preferable to `contains(text(), ...)`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible from pure [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).  It exists to pass a predicate that will determine which part of the XML structure you want returned.  In essence, you filter down to what you want, then do what you want with *that* outside of the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression.

So a working example would be something like:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml("<Invoice> <Note>Fatura Tipi:MM Alınan Mlz.İade<Note> </Invoice>");

XmlText node = xml.SelectSingleNode("//Note[contains(text(), 'Fatura Tipi:']/text())");

Console.WriteLine(node.Value.Split(':')[1]);
```

Comment: Actualy there are  2 xpath functions  .substring-before('aa-bb','-') and 
 tokenize("1,15,,24,50,", ",")  but I don't know how to combine one of  from these functions width  'contains' function.

Comment: @ilhan `tokenize` was introduced in XPath 2.0.  MSFT's implementation still runs on 1.0.